# openoffice writer java sdk replace text in a writer document

Tags: java, openoffice.org, openoffice-writer

I have searched on google but I can not find a solution for this. So I ask the StackOverflow community.

I want to use the SDK for OpenOffice (Java) to replace the text content in an OpenOffice Writer document.

How can I do that? The examples on the google search are helpless.

Answer (score 0):

You load the document, create a `textcursor`, navigate to the text to be replaced, select it, replace it with new text and save the document.

What have you tried so far?

You do know `MRI` extension, which can record the steps and produce code?

Comment: I use a another Software that make the job.

Answer (score -1):

How about the examples directly from Open Office for the sdk:

[Open Office SDK examples](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/API/Samples/Java)

The one under "Writer" called "TextReplace" should be precisely what you are looking for.